# How to Creat slide Out tab

Tags: jquery

I want to Slide Out tab in left of my web page, but it Slide in page by "bounce" effect, and slide out by another effect like "Clip", but I don't know how to do it?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried yourself by now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, this example scrolling the div when the user doesn't see the div any more:

```
//scrolling the output_code div to my view
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var set1 = $(document).scrollTop();
    var p = $("#output_code").position();

    if((set1 - p.top > 150)||(set1 - p.top < -700)){
        $('#output_code').animate({top:set1 + "px"},{duration:500,queue:false});
    }
});
```

if you want just to scroll it all the time:

```
//scrolling the output_code div to my view
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var set1 = $(document).scrollTop();
    var p = $("#output_code").position();
    $('#output_code').animate({top:set1 + "px"},{duration:500,queue:false});

});
```

of course change the #output_code to you div id.
GoodLuck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want something like using `.animate()` or `.effect()` with your `tab`s.

```
.animate()
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
.effect()
```

Check out *jquery-ui* so : http://jqueryui.com/effect/. 
But If you don't show us any `code`, we can't help you as well.